# Scipy spectrogram loop error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want to run `scipy.signal.spectrogram` in a loop with different `nperseg`, `noverlap`, and `nfft` each time. However I got:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Here is what I wrote:

```
Fs=10e3
data = testData(Fs)
r = []
for i in numpy.linspace(-0.4, 0.4, 9):
    t_step = 0.5+i
    f_step = 0.5-i

    window_length = round(2 * t_step * Fs)
    noverlap = round(t_step * Fs)
    nfft = round(Fs / f_step)

    arr_f, arr_t, fft = scipy.signal.spectrogram(data, Fs,
                                                 nperseg=window_length, 
                                                 noverlap=noverlap,
                                                 nfft=nfft,
                                                 window='hanning')
    r.append((arr_f, arr_t, fft))
```

where testData is copied from [spectrogram documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html),
Scipy version is 1.1.0.

When I run the same code with constant, hardcoded `t_step` and `f_step` (without +/- i) everything is going smoothly in the whole range. So here are my questions:

1. Why is it not working?
2. Is there a way not to do it manually?

Full Tracback:

```
File "/Users/desktop/test.py", line 34, in main window='hanning')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 691, in spectrogram input_length=x.shape[axis])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 1775, in _triage_segments win = get_window(window, nperseg)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site packages/scipy/signal/windows/windows.py", line 2106, in get_window return winfunc(*params)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/windows/windows.py", line 786, in hann return general_hamming(M, 0.5, sym)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/windows/windows.py", line 1016, in general_hamming return general_cosine(M, [alpha, 1. - alpha], sym)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/windows/windows.py", line 116, in general_cosine w = np.zeros(M)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Show the complete traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  There is useful information in there, including the line that generated the error.

Comment: Is `round` the builtin Python function or is it `numpy.round`?  It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could be run to reproduce the error.

Comment: `round` is Python built in function, otherwise I would write `numpy.round`. I wanted to do it this way. You just need to import 2 libraries and copy code from scipy.signal.spectrogram documentation. How can I improve it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations of `tstep` and `fstep` produce float numbers, but `scipy` expects integers. You could for instance change your code to

```
arr_f, arr_t, fft = signal.spectrogram(data, Fs,
                                     nperseg=window_length.astype(int), 
                                     noverlap=noverlap.astype(int),
                                     nfft=nfft.astype(int),
                                     window='hanning')
```

and `scipy` should work without problems. The `.astype(int)` just tweaks the numpy datatype, so instead of the float number `2000.0` scipy receives the integer number `2000`. [You can find more information about `numpy` data types in the official documentation.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html)

A better way is of course to change your calculations, so that they produce integers numbers right away.

Comment: This give answer to 2 question, thank you. I changed it to `int(round(x))` I still can't understand why `scipy` works without a loop with float numbers